# Google GCM server returns Unauthorized Error 401 while subscribing

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I get subscription success in app. But I see Google GCM server returns Unauthorized Error 401 in the server logs.

When I push a message from adapter, I get an authorization failure in server logs. But My adapter gives success response Notification sent to set user.

Can somebody tell me what could be the mistake I would be doing. (can this error also occur when my firewall is restricting this call.)

**While subscribing i was getting Reason: 401 unable to authenticate with gcm services. something like this. And While pushing a notification from adapter i was getting reason : unable to authenticate for Api key "ASYI-" with GCM. the error messages may not be exact but the message means just like above**

I am getting below error while sending notification

**Failed to invoke Google GCM push service.
GCM Service invocation failed (reason: Authentication has failed for sender key starting with 'AIzaSyCk')**

also getting below error

**GCM push token 'ssdsddsdsdsds' is not added to GCM notification key. GCM Service invocation failed (reason: Returned HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized when invoking GCM push service to get the notification key.)
GCM Service invocation failed (reason: Returned HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized when invoking GCM push service to get the notification key.)**

on the Android studio i see below error :
**GCMAPIClient$BackgroundRegistrationHandler.run in GCMAPIClient.java:130 :: Failed to register with GCM using Google Play Services. Error:Error :INVALID_SENDER**

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, i got some issue with my worksapce and had to create a new workspace this time i am not seeing any error on the console but when i send the notification the adpater says notification sent successfully to the set user. but the notification is not reaching the phone.

Comment: Errors that i saw in my previous workspace. While subscribing i was getting Reason. 401 unable to authenticate with gcm services. something like this. And While pushing a notification from adapter i was getting reason : unable to authenticate for Api key "ASYI-" with GCM. the error messages may not be exact but the message means just like above.

Comment: Why provide error logs that "looks something like this"? Why not provide the actual log when you're asked for the log? o_O - firewalls can restrict your calls to the Google servers. The error message suggets this.

Comment: I wasnt getting them... but later when i changed the network i got them,.

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: I changed the network and created a new workspace then i saw those errors appeared again.

Comment: The 401 (from GCM) coming in server logs and the INVALID_Sender in client logs point to invalid GCM sender id and key. Has the GCM credentials been modified?

Comment: No vivin not at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked for me, two things i did it to work.

1. Took the GCM.jar file from the sample project and placed it in my project . removed the other gcm dependencies
2. Created a project in FCM Console (https://console.firebase.google.com/)
   and took the google-services.json and placed it in my android studio project under app. Took the web API key from FCM Console and placed it in the mobilefirst app project.(There are two keys now one for app and other for web).

I had to create a new project in the fcm console and new keys..